# Reference examples in psychology of Bayesian prior updating for multiple studies?

Tags: regression, bayesian, prior, psychology

I'm new to applying Bayesian parameter estimation techniques in my research and am also hoping to help others in my area transition from frequentist to Bayesian methods. One thing that I am hoping to locate is several reference examples from the psychology (preferably social, health, or organizational psychology) or communications literature that uses results from a first study to update priors for subsequent studies in the same paper. Preferably, examples using likert-type survey day and where the process of how the priors were updated is relatively easy to understand for an audience new to Bayesian statistics.

Anyone have any go-to references on this, or other great resources for simple examples using likert-type data?

Comment: It isn't clear whether this is really about statistics, or is more about current practice / culture in psychology. This may be a better fit on the [cogsci.SE] SE site, or the [academia.SE] SE site, I'm not sure. *Please don't cross post.* If you don't get an answer here, you could delete this & try elsewhere.

Comment: If you are new to Bayesian methods, I hope you understand the issues well enough that you are using it for the right reasons. It is attractive to use informative priors so that you can do a future study with a smaller sample size than a classical frequentist approach that only uses the data from the study.  You really need tot think about how relevant the prior information is to your specific problem.  I am not trying to discourage the Bayesian approach.  For the most part statisticians do not consider the issue controversial the wy they did in the 1950s - 1980.

Answer (score 1):

Check

Michael Lee and
Eric-Jan Wagenmakers (2014).
[*Bayesian Cognitive Modeling: A Practical Course.*](https://bayesmodels.com) Cambridge University Press.

plus it's references and papers by the second author.

[John Kruschke](http://psych.indiana.edu/faculty/kruschke.php) also wrote papers on this subject.